# How to Share a Docker-Compose Volume in Distributed Cassandra Container using Docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, docker-swarm, elassandra

I have configured distributed version of `cassandra` using `Docker-Compose`.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  cassandra-masters:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: tasks.cassandra-masters    
  cassandra-slaves1:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: tasks.cassandra-masters
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: tasks.cassandra-slaves1
    depends_on:
     - cassandra-masters
```

After running the docker-compose file using `sudo docker stack deploy elassandra --compose-file docker-compose.yml`, everything works well and I can see them using `docker service ls` command.

**Problem:** What I want is that I don't know how to use volume in distributed  of containers. Is it like the normal configuration of docker-compose that found in [Docker's site](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)? or it is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** I have tried the named volumes like the following, There isn't any difference between this approach (distributed) and normal approach. The only thing that should be considered is that the volume should be shared:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  cassandra-masters:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: tasks.cassandra-masters
    volumes:
     - app-volume:/var/lib/cassandra

  cassandra-slaves1:
    image: strapdata/elassandra
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS: tasks.cassandra-masters
      CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS: tasks.cassandra-slaves1
    depends_on:
     - cassandra-masters
    volumes:
     - app-volume:/var/lib/cassandra
volumes:
  app-volume:
```